# Coloring dataframe column in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe generated by using read_sql. It has 6 columns. I want to color the text of one of the columns to red. I tried the below statement to color the column "Reviewer" but it doesn't work:

```
df2.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'red'},subset=['Reviewer']).
```

Can you please suggest what should I do?

I tried using applymap but that didn't work either.

Comment: Nothing to do with SQL Server, so I removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

See your pandas version do have ".style.set_properties" function, or pandas is up to date.
Sometimes they can be broken after installing some dependencies, like pandas can be depreciated in the process and you lose the function.